# Three.js canvas is resizing after events

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm making mobile-web using three.js.

Also I'm using meta view port tag,
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no; initial-scale:1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" >`

I have a problem that canvas is being resized after raycasting for click event.

canvas's element.style attribute changed:

```
<canvas width="1081" height="2029" style="width: 980px; height: 1081px;">
```

into

```
<canvas width="1081" height="2029" style="width: 412px; height: 773px;">

<!--
and changing size is depends on phone's screen size.. for mine is 412 x 773.
-->
```

I don't know where is changing and setting the canvas `style`.....

So I added below codes to css,

```
  .canvas{
    width: devicve-width !important;
    height: device-height !important;
  }

  canvas{
    width: devicve-width !important;
    height: device-height !important;
  }
```

and it doesn't work too.

Desktop-web is working fine, but only mobile version have the error.

I never reset the canvas's size, I don't know what I have to do.

Now, I have so many codes ( but there is no codes for re-size the canvas. ), so I'm very confused..

Is there any special code in three.js to set canvas's size?

Or any way to prevent it??

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the default ThreeJS example. The magical lines are the following.

```js
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
```

You can see how they are used [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html#L93-L100)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Three.js canvas size like so

```js
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks. Now I know where the size comes from, after the event window.innerWidth and innerHeight is changed.

I set the meta view port, but it doesn't work. Do you know the way to fix it?